# php code for replace "\" from a word, how possible

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

My php variable is like this:

```
$abc = "stack\overflow";
```

I want to remove `"\"` from `$abc`. I tried this:

```
$abc1 = str_replace("\", "N", $abc);
```

but this shows an error. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Please use an editor with syntax highlighting – it would have shown you `\", ` in the color that is used for strings. Everything behind `N", $abc);` would have been marked as a syntax error. Even the syntax highlighting on this very website is displaying that error. (You see, the N is in black, whereas string contents are in brown/orange)

Comment: shouldn't you be looking at how it got in to the variable in the first place ?

Comment: @Dagon Maybe it is an user input

Comment: @Dagon `\o` isn’t an escape sequence, so you can just enter the backslash that way.

Comment: *maybe* its many things which why knowing the source matters

Answer (score 2):

`\` is a special character that is escaping your quotas, that's why your string doesn't end... Simply use `$abc1 = str_replace("\\", "N", $abc);` - it will work.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, edited, you have to replace it by double slash \

```
$abc="stack\overflow";

$abc1= str_replace("\\", "N", $abc);
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash `\` is the escape character for [php strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), that usually means that you can’t just use it like that an expect it to work as just a backslash character. Instead, it is used to define escape sequences, used to represent other characters which can’t be expressed otherwise. This makes the backslash a special character as well, which needs to be escaped too.

In your original text, the backslash is before an `o`. `\o` is not an escape sequence, so the backslash is actually interpreted as its own character. In the `str_replace` call however, you are using the backslash before the closing quotation mark. This escapes the quotation mark, preventing the string from ending. If you want to just replace the backslash, you will have to escape it:

```
$abc1 = str_replace("\\", "N", $abc);
```